# Open Windows 10 VPN via rasdial or rasphone

Tags: windows, vpn, batch

I'm trying to auto-start a Windows 10 VPN via batch script instead of clicking several times to start it. I tried it with the command

```
rasdial.exe "MYVPNNAME" "USERNAME" "PASSWORD"
```

but I'm getting a "RAS-Error 703".

I also tried

```
rasphone -d "MYVPNNAME"
```

which DOES open the windows modal to enter credentials and connect, they even are already inserted, but it shows the error:

[image]

(it says error with userscript (to update routing table).

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Please use correct markdown for `monospaced code`

Comment: Your `rasphone` looks very strange. It’s supposed to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbxGx.png) on Windows 10. // What type of VPN is this? Why does it involve executing a script?